# Как отобрать компоненты?

Tags: c#, winforms, консоль

Есть csv из 1000 процессоров. Нужно отобрать их по сокетам и производителю, в ксв есть только производитель, название процессора, пример:

```
Type,Part Number,Brand,Model,Rank,Benchmark,Samples,URL 

CPU,BX8070110900K,Intel,Core i9-10900K,1,103,883,https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Intel-Core-i9-10900K/Rating/4071
```

к примеру, 1151 v2 = (лист процессоров), 1151 = (лист процессоров). Есть идея, как это реализовать. Нужно как-то отделить их, например, я знаю, что в 1151 v2 Входят такие процессоры: i3 8xxx, i5 8xxx, i7 8xxx, i9 9xxx, i3 9xxx, i5 9xxx, i7 9xxx, вот по такому типу он бы их отбирал, вариант с Reg выражением может? Я не знаю, подскажите)

Comment: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: @aepot Подключена. Какие дальнейшие действия посоветуете?

Comment: @aepot Они у меня отобраны, просто нужно их раскидать по сокетам. Не знаю как...

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос, и напишите, что именно у вас не получается.

Comment: Немного погуглил, например можно попробовать распарсить вот этот [сайт](https://www.techpowerup.com/cpu-specs/) и создать свою базу данных соответствия процессоров и сокетов. Или еще поискать, может API или готовые данные где-то есть.

Comment: Если сайт не дает такую информацию, то вы не узнаете сокет. У вас несколько вариантов: 1. Искать по коду процессора на другом ресурсе его сокет например предоставленный вами процессор имеет [BX8070110900K](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/199332/intel-core-i9-10900k-processor-20m-cache-up-to-5-30-ghz.html) и сайт выдает `Sockets Supported`. 2. Искать другой ресурс, где в базе будет вся необходимая информация. 3. Делать костыли, подобные, которые предложили вы, с поиском по названию, тогда берите название модели и делайте `if (name.StartWith("Core I9"))`, но это костыль.

Comment: @aepot сайт выглядит годно, пишет 1000+ процессоров, но как их вывести все, без фильтров? Не могу что-то разобраться, попробую еще, но может Вы знаете? Я имею ввиду, выбрал интел, пишет, что там 1000+, а выводит 101 процессор.

Comment: Too many results found, first 100 displayed. Please refine search parameters.

Comment: Это уже творческая задача, опять же, можно еще поискать, я всего-лишь первый попавшийся пример привел.